# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function. while trying to render a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of DashboardCards.

`

Im trying to have icons and labels in a common file constants/drawer

```js
import DashboardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Dashboard";

export const MainMenuItems = [
  {
    label: "Dashboard",
    icon: <DashboardIcon />,
    redirectLink: "/",
  },
];
```

and in the `main.js` file importing them and trying to map them.

Here i want to pass some props to Icon like `<Icon size="small"/>`.

```js
import { MainMenuItems } from "../constants/drawer.js";
const MainContainer=()=>{

return (
<>

     {MainMenuItems.map(({label,icon:Icon}) => {
        
          return (
              <div>
<Icon size="small"/>

              </div>
            )
          );
        })}

</>
)

}
```

Comment: The error points to your `DashboardCards` component, which you have not shared. Assuming you are using `MainContainer` within `DashboardCards`, have you actually exported `MainContainer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Icon` variable holds the component, you just need to execute it in the `main.js` file.

```
import { MainMenuItems } from "../constants/drawer.js";
const MainContainer = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {MainMenuItems.map(({ label, icon: Icon }) => {
                return <div>{Icon}</div>;
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to pass props to the component, I suggest you to just save the component reference to the icon property.

```
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";

export const MainMenuItems = [
  {
    label: "Dashboard",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    redirectLink: "/",
  },
];
```

main.js

```
import { MainMenuItems } from "../constants/drawer.js";
const MainContainer = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {MainMenuItems.map(({ label, icon: Icon }) => {
                return <div><Icon size="small" /></div>;
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: hi there thanks for the response . i wanna pass some props to the icon like `<Icon size="small" />`  what would you suggest in that case?

Comment: @Vigneshs, you are welcome, I just update the answer, please check again.

Comment: hi @mina , i tried your suggestion . i got another error there `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @Vigneshs, are you sure you pass the component reference like this `icon: DashboardIcon,` not `icon: <DashboardIcon />,`?

Comment: this error was from another page. i resolved everything and its fine now . thank you very much @mina :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write import statement for `<DashboardIcon />` in constants/drawer.js

```
import DashboardIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Dashboard';

export const MainMenuItems = [
  {
    label: "Dashboard",
    icon: <DashboardIcon />,
    redirectLink: "/",
  },
];
```

In main.js, we have to execute Icon as a value Icon have component in it.

```
import { MainMenuItems } from "../constants/drawer.js";

const MainContainer = () => {
   return (
    <>
     {MainMenuItems.map(({label, icon: Icon}) => {  
          return (
              <div>
               {Icon}
              </div>
            )
          );
      })}
    </>
   );
}
```